# How do I test if a Javascript object has only empty objects at the last nested level?

Tags: javascript

I have an object that has other objects inside it **up to n levels**. I want to check if the object only contains other objects. Like this:

```
var emptyObj = {
    obj1 : {
        obj1a : {},
        obj1b : {}
    },
    obj2 : {},
    obj3 : {
        obj3a : {
            obj3aa : {}
        }
    }
};
```

Changing the data structure is **not** an option. No jQuery.

-- edit--

If there is anything apart from an empty object `{}` at the last level, the test should fail.
Failure examples:

```
var notEmpty1 = {
    obj1 : []
};
var notEmpty2 = {
    obj1: {
        obj1a: ""
    },
    obj2: {}
};
```

Comment: The answer is: recursion.

Comment: please clarify, I can write recursive `function` but I don't understand the question

Comment: @WhiteHat I think he wants to check that the properties of the object are: not arrays, functions etc. Just objects.

Comment: Sorry, after reading the post again I realized it was not clear. There should be only empty objects at the leaf level.

Comment: @maow Not sure I said it's the only possible answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An object is empty if it's, well, an object, and every one of its keys is in turn an empty object.

```
function empty(o) {

  function isObject()      { return o && o.constructor === Object; }
  function keyEmpty(key)   { return empty(o[key]; }
  function everyKeyEmpty() { return Object.keys(o) . every(keyEmpty); }

  return isObject() && everyKeyEmpty();
}
```

Note that if an object has zero keys then "every" one of the zero keys passes the condition.

Comment: Very good solution.
I changed the second line to return true when !o, so `{key: undefined}` is understood as `{}`

Comment: Do really want `{key: undefined}` to be treated as empty? Actually, there's a subtle difference.

Comment: Yes, it is different, you are right. Your solution fits the answer as it was asked perfectly.